# Loading many fragments / being able to go back and forth from one to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an app with many different pages all with different layouts. I created my own xml file and .java for each fragment, like so.

```
public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather, container, false);
            return view;
    }
}
```

I have over 100 .java files like this referencing different .xml files. I need a way to toggle back and forth between all my different fragments. What should I do?

Comment: You may want to refine your question to state what you mean by "toggle back and forth". Do you mean you are moving laterally between fragments (like in a ViewPager), up and down between fragments (by inflating a new fragment if a button is pressed) or displaying many different fragments at once (like in a ListView)?

Comment: toggle back and forth. So there would be left and right arrows the top of the screen. And the rest of the screen would be a fragment. Using left and right arrows to cycle through many fragments

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your fragments are in a set order, you could use a ViewPager with a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) and use the ViewPager's setCurrentItem() method to go left and right. Just save the current position in your activity and make your left and right arrows increment and decrement that integer.

In your Activity

```
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mCurrent;
}

public int incrementPosition() {
    if (mCurrent >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS) 
        mCurrent = MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS;

    return mCurrent;
}

public int decrementPosition() {
    if (mCurrent <= 0) 
        mCurrent = 0;

    return mCurrent;
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // return the fragment for that position
    }
}
```

In the onCreate() of the activity

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());

mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_previous);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(decrementPosition());
    }
});
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_next);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(incrementPosition());
    }
});
```